# Get UserToken from Logon ID (LUID) (C++)

Tags: windows, session, sessionid, terminal-services

I'm trying to understand better how Windows sessions work, so if I have some weird mistakes in the question, please, let me know.

I use `LsaEnumerateLogonSessions()` to get all the logged on sessions in the system.
Now I have LUID that represents a log-on, and if I understand correctly, it represents a user that logged on or a build it user like SYSTEM.

Now, if user X starts a process, Windows gives that process a token that represents X.

Is there a way (in a Windows service) to get the user's token from LUID?
I know I can get it from a process HANDLE, but that is not what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`LsaGetLogonSessionData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa378290(v=VS.85).aspx) to get the session id and then use [`WTSQueryUserToken`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383840(v=vs.85).aspx) to get the token from that. Note that you may need to run as LocalSystem for `WTSQueryUserToken` (see "[How can I get the current user token for the physical session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1288965/how-can-i-get-the-current-user-token-for-the-physical-session)" regarding that).

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer!!! :-)

That is what I am trying now, and it is not good enough:
Assume user X is connected to the console.
If the LUID belongs to user SYSTEM, than LsaGetLogonSessionData() returns sessionID 0. Calling WTSQueryUserToken() returns the token of user X and not of SYSTEM.

Comment: OK, seems like [OpenTokenByLogonId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff714513.aspx) is what you need then.

Comment: Thanks, it looks like the right function !
Although I guess it is not that simple or even possible to call from my process.
If I manage to perform what I want I will print the code.

Thanks again! :-)